# AM_PROG_LEX and undefined yywrap

Tags: flex-lexer, lex, autoconf, rhel6

My program uses the documented autoconf macro `AM_PROG_LEX`. It builds fine on `RHEL 6.5` and other distros, but fails on `RHEL 6.6` and later.

The configure script cannot compile its tests. When it tries gcc with `-ll`, `-lfl`, linking fails with:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfl
```

When it tries gcc without extra libraries, linking fails with:

```
undefined reference to `yywrap'
```

`libfl.a` or `libfl.so` is missing from official repos of those systems. On RHEL 6.5 it's part of `flex` package.

```
RHEL 6.5
configure:5334: checking whether yytext is a pointer
configure:5351: gcc -o conftest -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -O0   conftest.c -lfl  >&5
configure:5351: $? = 0
configure:5359: result: yes


RHEL 6.8
configure:5196: checking whether yytext is a pointer
configure:5217: gcc -o conftest -g -O2   conftest.c   >&5
/tmp/ccNJtVgv.o: In function `input':
/home/git/rpmbuild/BUILD/snacc-1.3.1_16_g23ba7a6/lex.yy.c:1168: undefined reference to `yywrap'
/tmp/ccNJtVgv.o: In function `yylex':
/home/git/rpmbuild/BUILD/snacc-1.3.1_16_g23ba7a6/lex.yy.c:867: undefined reference to `yywrap'
/tmp/ccNJtVgv.o: In function `main':
/home/git/rpmbuild/BUILD/snacc-1.3.1_16_g23ba7a6/conftest.l:17: undefined reference to `yywrap'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:5224: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
...
configure:5246: result: no
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`libfl` contains two and only two functions, both of which are normally unnecessary in production use of flex:

```
int main() { extern int yylex(void); while (yylex()) ; return 0; }
int yywrap(void) { return 1; }
```

The `yywrap` implementation (which essentially disables the yywrap functionality) is not necessary if you use the option

```
%option noyywrap
```

in your flex definition, or if you pass the command-line option `--noyywrap` to flex.

For quick-and-dirty flex scanners, or for debugging, it is sometimes handy to be able to use `libfl` to fill in the above functions. But it also can create problems on systems which provide both 32- and 64-bit environments. For this reason, `libfl` was removed from the RHEL `flex` rpm in 2014. See this [RedHat bug fix advisory](https://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHBA-2014-1402.html) for details.

So you could install the appropriate `flex-devel` rpm in order to have `libfl` available. Or you could compile it yourself using the above code (which is not *precisely* the source code you'll find in the flex source bundle, but should produce precisely the same library).

Or you could try to fix autoconf so that it doesn't depend on `libfl`. It didn't used to have any such dependency; if it couldn't find `libfl`, it would just assume that it wasn't required for the program being compiled.

Comment: won't `--noyywrap` break programs that provide their own implementation of yywrap?

Comment: @basin: yes, I wouldn't suggest forcing that option globally. But you could use it in  the autoconf test programs.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround is to install `flex-devel` package containing `libfl.a`. RHEL version available to subscribers ony. Alternative is CentOS package or recompiling from source.